# JWT token support in React application along with Refresh token and http-only-cookie

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, cookies, jwt

I'm implementing support for logging in and sending requests to the API. However, I don't understand how to properly handle the returned JWT token and Refresh token.
Framework - React / NextJS 13

Here's what the current implementation looks like.

1. I call fetch to the external server on which the API is hosted. I do a POST to the endpoint /Login/
2. This is what my JSON response looks like

```
{
  "id": "d6669a68-5afb-432d-858f-3f5181579a90",
  "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6ImQ2NjY5YTY4LTVhZmItNDMyZC04NThmLTNmNTE4MTU3OWE5MCIsImVtYWlsIjoiYWRtaW5Ac2Nob29sc3luYy5wbCIsIm5hbWUiOiJTdXBlciIsImZhbWlseV9uYW1lIjoiQWRtaW4iLCJyb2xlIjoiU3VwZXJBZG1pbiIsIm5iZiI6MTcwNTE1NzUyNiwiZXhwIjoxNzA1MTU3ODI2LCJpYXQiOjE3MDUxNTc1MjZ9.FuSmB-suEYkWeIfbDryjFQ4eEWcQIlbC0NHgj943f3XA_aARNLl75ppzLY6tpo-E2vKys-785Miv4qcj-cOarQ",
  "username": "Super Admin"
}
```

With this response additionally a http-only cookie is set with RefreshToken

[image: cookies]

1. And now to make a request to another endpoint requiring authorization then in the header I pass this token.

```js
      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}`
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
      });
```

Is that how it should work?
Should I also save this token received after login as a cookie?

Will the Refresh token now automatically be sent with every request to the server?

If this returned token is http-only is it automatically included in the request to the server?
I don't have to add an extra parameter to the fetch function?

Thank you in advance for any answerand explanation.

Comment: what is `authToken`?

Comment: The refresh token should never be sent to the API, its a secret for the application to use only.

Comment: @JaromandaX is the token that was returned in JSON from the endpoint /Login